# Replacing instead of adding prefix in batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename, prefix, goto

I`m writing a batch script file to add prefix to all .txt files in same folder with batch file

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
    exit /b
)

:loop
if "%1"=="" goto end

rename "%1" "abc%1"
shift
goto loop

:end
```

I call this file in cmd like this:

```
file.bat *.txt
```

However i couldnt understand why this code replace prefix . For example if i have textfile.txt this make it abctfile.txt but i need to add prefix to make it abctextfile.txt. This is task for me to use marks and goto without using for command.

I tried with this code which work for for command. Also i try to add it end of filename. For example
textfile.txt => textfile.txtabc

Comment: The requirement to not use a `for` loop suggests this is homework, so I won't give you a "copy and paste" solution. That said, `rename` works a bit differently from other commands (especially with wildcards. There is a good description on [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)), so you need to create the new filename *before*  using `rename` (using a variable with the `set` command - see `set /?` for details) and use `rename` without wildcards (`%1` contains a wildcard in your example).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework question, I'll just give you hints:

1. Execute a `dir /b /a-d "%1"`  command to list the existing filenames, and redirect this list to a temporary file, say `temp.dat`
2. Read the first line of that file into a variable using `set /p oldfilename<temp.dat`
3. Delete the filename from the list using `findstr /v /x /L /c:"%oldfilename%" <temp.dat >temp2.dat`, which finds all of the strings in `temp.dat` which (/v) do NOT match (/x) eXactly (/L) Literally (`/c:"somestring"`) the string and redirects the result to `temp2.dat`
4. Move `temp2.dat` over `temp.dat` so you have a new `temp.dat` file containing  the new list
5. Rename the file `%oldfilename%`
6. go back to (2)

Some further hints:

to determine whether there is text data in a file, use

```
set "var="
set /p var=<filename
if "%var%"=="" goto nomoredata
```

The first line ensures that `var` is "empty". the second reads from the file which will either set `var` to *something* or leave it "empty" if there is no data on the file.

Technically, setting a variable to *empty* deletes the variable from the environment. You can also test whether the variable is *empty* by using `if [not] defined var` - where the `not` is optional (which is why it's shown in [square brackets]) - but probably you haven't encountered that yet.

A command may generate a normal response (like `dir` will generate a file-list) and possibly an error response (like when it can't rename a file). Sometimes it's desirable to suppress the responses. Appending `>nul` to the line will suppress the normal response, and `2>nul` the error response.

If you have an error response, the variable `errorlevel` will usually be set to non-zero (zero meaning "no error"). **Immediately** after a command (such as `ren`), you can test `errorlevel` to determine whether there was an error. Two common ways : `if %errorlevel%==0`  and `if errorlevel n` (where `n` is a number. The first tests `errorlevel` to be exactly equal to `0` (although `==` can also be `geq` for greater than or equal to and `0` can be any numeric to suit various situations). The second means `if the errorlevel is *n* or greater than *n*.

`ren` will set `errorlevel` to `0` only if the rename was successful.

Now suppose you are prefixing files with `abc` and your existing files are

```
123abc.txt
456abc.txt
789abc.txt
abc456abc.txt
```

When you come to renaming `456abc.txt` to `abc456abc.txt`, `ren` will object since that filename already exists, and it will set `errorlevel` to `1`.

If **on the line directly after the ren command** you code `if %errorlevel% neq 0 echo %oldfilename%>>temp.dat` then `456abc.txt` will be appended (`>>`) to the file; later `abc456abc.txt` will be renamed `abcabc456abc.txt` and then `456abc.txt` can be renamed `abc456abc.txt`